# Is there a Roadmap for ASP.NET Framework

Tags: asp.net

Is there a roadmap for ASP.NET Framework edition? If so, where can I find it? I though I heard, at one point, that, even though most development is happening on ASP.NET Core, that some features would be back-ported to Framework or Standard.

Comment: I don't want to get into a philosophical debate about what constitutes a legit question, but just consider: If Google cannot help developers to find the ASP.NET Framework roadmap (which it can't), perhaps SO can... It's important information for those of use who maintain large codebases.

Comment: Where do you think we get our info from? :-)

Comment: If it's not public info then maybe there's a newsletter or something you can sign up for.